# Difference between setRepeatingRequest and setRepeatingBurst?

Tags: android, android-camera, camera2

API level 21 introduced camera2, with it **setRepeatingRequest** and **setRepeatingBurst**. I have read the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html) here, but still cannot catch the difference between the two. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you'll notice that the constructors for these two methods are slightly different. `setRepeatingBurst`'s first argument is `List<CaptureRequest>`, and `setRepeatingRequests`'s is just a `CaptureRequest`.

According to the docs,

**setRepeatingBurst**

> With this method, the camera device will continually capture images, cycling through the settings in the provided list of CaptureRequests, at the maximum rate possible.

**setRepeatingRequest**

> With this method, the camera device will continually capture images using the settings in the provided CaptureRequest, at the maximum rate possible.

So, `setRepeatingBurst` can be used to capture images with a list of different settings.

That's my best understanding, hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

1. Think of **setRepeatingRequest** as **ONE CaptureRequest** with one set of settings to continually capture images.
2. Where as in **setRepeatingBurst** there is a list **CaptureRequest** and each "CaptureRequest" has its own setting to continually capture images.

Conclusion: **setRepeatingBurst** call is like making multiple **setRepeatingRequest** calls in one call.